# Pandas pip install

Tags: python, pandas

Hello guys I have the following issue for this code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

`Module not found`

I am running python3.9 but visualizing the mistake it says the package is running through python 3.8...how can I address this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of questions...

1. Have you pip installed the pandas module?
2. If you have, what version is installed on your system?  You can find this by running the pd.**version** command.

You can check your Python version by entering “which python” or “python —version” and you can check your pip version with “which pip”

Just to make sure you’ve got all of the moving parts needed to run the pandas module.

From what I’ve read about this issue, you may need to download the “wheel” module as well.  You will want to enter these command:

Python 3
sudo python3 -m pip install wheel
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas

The other issue I’ve seen is that the version of pandas isn’t in sync with the version of Python that you’re running...  if the version of pandas is set up for Python 2.x, Python 3 won’t find the purposed module.

If that’s the case trying using pip3:

pip3 install wheel
pip3 install pandas

Not sure if any of this helps at all, but best of luck and I’m open to any and all feedback!